# App getting users while app is under review by google play

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have published an app on google play, last night I have submitted a 1.0.4 update for my app which is still under review, but I have noticed that new users are registering with app version 1.0.4.

But my problem is that I never shared APK with anyone, I just generated aab file and uploaded it on play console then how is it possible?

The same issue occured with my last update which I ignored. Please let me know if it is common because I naver faced this type of problem with any of my previous apps.

Comment: Probably google play store team using your app for testing. They were created those users may be.

Comment: Initially, I thought the same but registered emails look real.

Comment: This might as well result from automated tests (Pre-launch reports) Google Play automatically executes when you upload a new artifact. If you support Sign in with Google, those tests try to sign in.